# master-worker server with AnyEvent

Tags: perl, events, asynchronous

I need to write a server program that will open and keep 5 live Telnet, SSH and various connections to a server, while it listens to JSONRPC calls on the other side.

I've no problem with opening and maintaining the 5 connections, and listening for requests:

```
# workers:
open_myconnections( 1..5 );
my $w1 = AnyEvent->timer (interval => $seconds, cb => sub { keep_conn_alive(1) });
my $w2 = AnyEvent->timer (interval => $seconds, cb => sub { keep_conn_alive(2) });
...

# now listen for requests
use AnyEvent::JSONRPC::Lite;
# master: 
my $server = jsonrpc_server '127.0.0.1', '4423';
$server->reg_cb(
    queue_up => sub {
        my ($res_cv, @params) = @_;
        my $res = send_params_to_connection_queue( @params ); 
        $res_cv->result($res);
    },
);
```

But now I'm stuck trying to figure out the best way (ie the **non-blocking**, [AnyEvent](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/POE) way) to distribute the queue among the 5 workers, which is what my function  `send_params_to_connection_queue()` does.

Any module suggestion is appreciated, although I'm trying to avoid using [POE](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/POE) since this is supposed to be a **very tiny server** and, unless no other sensible option exists, I'll pass.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly distribution means in this case, could you elaborate?

Comment: I mean, to assign an incoming request to one of the 5 workers available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At YAPC::NA 2011 I learned about a very nice queueing system called ZeroMQ.  With Perl Bindings at [Direct Perl Bindings](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/ZeroMQ) and [AnyEvent bindings](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aZeroMQ).

```
                                                |----- ssh worker
JSONRPC-Listener-EventLoop---->QueueingSystem---|----- telnet worker
                                                |----- etc.
```

Comment: There's also AnyMQ and AnyEvent::MP (the latter is mostly only interesting when you have multiple processes / nodes)

Comment: AnyEvent::MP is great! I'll probably use that. But my problem is that Net::OpenSSH and Telnet are blocking libraries and that makes it really hard to use an event queue.

Comment: You use a non-blocking main event loop, which non-blockingly queue the work to be fulfilled by the blocking service (telnet, etc.), main loop also sets a callback function so that when the queue woker is done with the blocking call, it can signal back to the main loop which runs the callback, and in general postprocesses the data, and sends it pack to the events requestor.    I drew a picture in my reply above.

Answer (score 2):

Only you know what is "best", but there is a general pattern on how to do this, and maybe that is your real question.

Basically, you need a queue, say, an array, that stores all requests not yet sent:

my @queue;

then, each time you want to do a request, you first push the data onto the queue, and then call a "scheduler" function:

sub do_req {
      my ($data, $cb) = @_;
      push @queue, [$data, $cb];
      scheduler;
   }

The purpose of the schedule function is to select a worker and fire off the
next request:

sub scheduler {
      @queue or return; # nothing to do with empty queue

```
  for my $worker (@workers) {
     if ("$worker is free") {
        my ($data, $cb) = @{ shift @queue };
        $worker->doit (sub {
           &scheduler;
           $cb->(@_); # call original callback
        });
        return;
     }
  }
```

}

What this does is to find a free worker, send a request to it ("doit"), and
when it's finished, it calls the scheduler again.

It's up to you how you decide whether a worker is "free". For example, you
could always select the worker with the least number of outstanding requests.
Or you could choose a worker that has, say, less than 5 outstanding requests.
Or whichever way is best.

The important thing is, whenever a worker might become free (because a job
finishes), you call the scheduler again, to queue the next job.

This way you can impose arbitrary limits on the workers, while not forgetting
about jobs you need to do but couldn't send due to thise limits.

There are many variatins to this technique, but the basic idea is always the
same: first queue stuff, then have a function that you call both after
queueing and after a job is done, which then should distribute the queued
work.

In event speak, there are two events when you might need to send out a
request: when a new job/request is created/queued, and when an outstanding
job is done.